# How to capture and store a video in h.264 format using web browsers without Flash?

Tags: javascript, html, ffmpeg, html5-video, h.264

**How to capture a video** and **store** it in **h.264 format** using web browsers without flash?

As per my analysis, **HTML5** can be used to access the camera and microphone **without** any additional **plug-ins** as in this link. "http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/"

However, **i don't know** the possibility of **storing** the video in h.264 format.

I would prefer **not to install any additional plugins. However if its not possible without any additional plugins, i would accept it. I can also use **Java Applets** if needed.

**Is HTML 5 the only option or it possible with JScript itself?**  I also hope that **ffmpeg can help me too.**

Answer (score 3):

3 years later it is now possible to **record H.264 video** in the browser with **Chrome 52** (Jul 20, 2016) and the **Media Recorder API** without plugins or Java or Flash.

Chrome 52 is the 1st to support both the Media Recorder API and H.264 for video encoding. Chrome 49,50 and 51 only supported VP8 & VP9 as video codecs and Chrome 48- did not the support Media Recorder API.

**The audio codec used is still Opus @ 48kHz** and the container is .webm so if you'll still have to pass the file through FFmpeg if you want wide browser/device support.

[This article](https://blog.addpipe.com/mediarecorder-api/) (co-wroted by me) covers the Media Recorder API in detail across Firefox and Chrome and there's this [Media Recorder API demo that supports H.264](https://addpipe.com/media-recorder-api-demo/) encoding on Chrome 52 + the associated code as a [GitHub project](https://github.com/addpipe/Media-Recorder-API-Demo).

Disclaimer: I work at Pipe where we handle video recording.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet, but it looks like it's coming.

There is a draft specification for [MediaStream Recording](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/), but it has not been implemented in any browsers yet. There is a [ticket](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=262211) to build it into Chrome, that you can track.

Someone built a Javascript library to [record video into WebM](http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/31486670538/creating-webm-video-from-getusermedia), though it doesn't do audio. It uses the browser's built-in function to save a WebP image to do the encoding. In theory, you could write an h.264 encoder in Javascript, but it would be very slow and quite difficult to write.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other alternative solutions if i go for additional plugins or using java applets.

Comment: I would steer clear of Java applets, but a google search will turn up a number of Flash video recorders. I do not have a specific one to recommend.

Comment: Yeah.. However,My situation is not to go with Flash.. There are some libraries like JFFMPG.. Anyway, each has its own limitations and has a lot of problems...I will be grateful if i get a tried and proven approach from anyone who has experienced in this area like you.

Comment: I'm curious, why is Flash not an option?